# Decode MGVC blu-ray

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, vlc, blu-ray

I downloaded iso of Studio Ghibli animation blu-ray. It contains a "KDM" folder (60 GB, while the m2ts files combined is 30GB), which indicates that it's a MGVC blu-ray disk. It's alleged that this improves the video quality. I tried VLC, handbrake, makemkv, and DVDFab but none recognizes this format. Is there a software that can decode this format or is there any configuration I can change in the aforementioned software so that they can decode this format?

Comment: Will it play on a blu-ray player? Perhaps it is coded to not be rippable…

Comment: @SolarMike It's a rip so I don't have the blu-ray disc (also, I'm in China and these production seems to be limited to sell in Japan, so I can't buy one either). And I don't have a blu-ray player that supports this feature: these are also limited to sell in Japan.

Comment: what is the format of the files inside the KDM folder?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz `file` says that it's just data.

Comment: The file extension is `.bin`.

Comment: From what I've read, MGVC is a Japan-only, Panasonic-only video format with more bandwidth for video (60Mbps), which will allow you to see 36-bit color. It seems it never took off, the articles being from 2013. I'd say you'll be better served by a "normal" 4K release, which may be the m2ts files already on your disc.
https://www.avsforum.com/threads/36-bit-mgvc-blu-ray-only-in-japan.1486405/

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Unfortunately Studio Ghibli films are not available in 4K blu-ray.